# rails: customize reload! to check syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-console

I'd like to customize the rails console `reload!` command such that after reloading it'll also check syntax, e.g. with `ruby -c`.

Following `Caillou`'s answer I tried adding the following to `#reload!` at `railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/console/app.rb`

```
# you may want to include other dirs too
files = Dir[Rails.root + 'lib/**/*.rb']
files.each {|f| `ruby -c #{f}`}
```

but I get an error when checking files which use gems from github, e.g.

`` bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:191:in `rescue in load_spec_files': git://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first. (Bundler::GitError) ``

However, running `ruby -c` on the same file from shell prints `syntax OK`

Comment: Why do you need to check the syntax? If it's invalid your code will error out anyway.

Comment: If you access it later, it'll error only after a long time

Comment: That's *exactly* why having a robust set of model, controller and integration tests is essential. If you don't have those that's the first problem you should fix.

Comment: Right, but why not both? If I introduce a syntax error in a lib, I'd like it to fail fast

Comment: Running `rake test` should take a minimal amount of time and will expose syntax problems almost immediately. It'll also trap other regressions. I find in practice syntax errors are the least of your problems. When working on a model, always have the associated test open and run that repeatedly as you iterate. Any minor mistakes will be caught before they can get lost. When working on a controller, same idea, either exercise the page through a browser or command-line tool, or run the tests. There's no "reload everything" feature in Rails, it loads as necessary.

Comment: So you run `rspec` after each reload?

Comment: Not after each reload, that'd be way too slow. After each significant code change, absolutely. Generally whatever's wired up to `rake test`, if that's `rspec` or otherwise. I'm not sure what you're doing where `reload!` is such a critical part of your workflow, so maybe you could expand on that. The whole point of that feature is to *quickly* reset the state of the console, so bogging it down with heaps of functionality is counter-productive. Why not define your own command that does what you want and incidentally calls `reload!` as a side-effect?

Comment: My workflow:

1. edit a file to play with a new feature

2. `reload!` to update the console

3. run some manual test

4. after the feature works basically, I run the full rspec


Step 3 might take some time before accessing a library class with a potential syntax error, so I need an immediate indication. Anyhow, I'll embrace your suggestion for a new command.

Comment: I'd try and steer towards using model and controller tests when iterating on things like that, they're a lot more comprehensive than manually exercising things. Generally I only use the console for performing manual updates, creating records, or doing bulk manipulation that's easier to do in Ruby than in the database. Hope you can find something that fixes your problem, though!

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to `#reload!` at `railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/console/app.rb` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272463/how-to-check-ruby-syntax-error-in-ruby-code):

```
# you may want to include other dirs too
files = Dir[Rails.root + 'lib/**/*.rb'] + Dir[Rails.root + 'app/**/*.rb']
# fix for git mergetool
files.reject!{ |f| f =~ /_(BACKUP|BASE|REMOTE|LOCAL)_/}
files.each{ |f| RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_file(f) }
```

Comment: Nice, you found out what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the class hosting the `reload!` method like this :

```
method(:reload!)
=> #<Method: Object(Rails::ConsoleMethods)#reload!>
```

I guess you should re-open the `Rails::ConsoleMethods` class and override the `reload!` method to add the behavior you need. But I didn't succeed to do it myself, maybe someone else can add his knowledge to the answer.

Here's what I tried :

```
class Rails::ConsoleMethods
  def reload!
    super
    puts "test"
  end
end
```

It doesn't print my "test" string when I use `reload!`. I don't know what's wrong, but I'm almost sure this is what you need to do.

Comment: Thx, I manage to print "test", but it prints even when I introduce syntax errors. I tried to modify `reload!`. See updated question.

Comment: Have you tried to run "bundle install", as the error message tells you ?

Comment: Yes, but it had no effect. As I said, it works fine from the shell.